# How to show form with specific fields to the user after registration

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I would like to show the form to the user with additional fields to fill after the registration. This will help me to have the very simple registration form (username, email, password) and after that I will ask all additional info in that new form so as not to bother people during the registration time.

I would like to have something like it's present at SO or linkedin when they propose you to have a guide or to fill in something with a small notification.

But, what I need is that this information from the form is added to the user profile table in DB.

What I did for the moment is the new user profile plugin which adds new section to the registration form with all additional questions. So, what I need now is to show this section not during the registration of the user but after he enters the site.

Does anyone has any idea how this can be achieved or any extension that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I've finished by using BTLogin plugin which is easily customizable and has nice features. [BTLogin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/bt-login) extension can be found on Joomla extensions page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a developer, I highly recommend RSForm! Pro - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/rsform-pro . It costs money, but with many options and great support it's well worth it.

If you are a developer, a simple Joomla plugin should do the trick to fire up your form after the user has successfully logged in (registration completed). Specifically I would use the 'onUserAuthorisation' event - https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

Good Luck!
-Nick